# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'DBNAME.TABLENAME' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I always get this error when executing this query, I've tried creating a new database and restarting, checked for any syntax error but found none.
This is the code that gets the error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SolarTV`.`TABASSINANTES` (
  `CDCAD` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `TELEFONE` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `NOMETITULAR` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `HRPDIA` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOPLANO` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `CNPJ` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `CDCONTR` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `CDCONTA` INT(11) NULL,
  `CPF` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `HPD` TINYINT(4) NULL,
  `HPS` TINYINT(4) NULL,
  `HPM` TINYINT(4) NULL,
  `HPA` TINYINT(4) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CDCAD`),
  INDEX `fk_TABASSINANTES_2_idx` (`CDCONTA` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_TABASSINANTES_1_idx` (`CPF` ASC, `CDCONTR` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_TABASSINANTES_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CDCONTA`)
    REFERENCES `SolarTV`.`TABCONTAS` (`CDCONTA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_TABASSINANTES_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CPF` , `CDCONTR`)
    REFERENCES `SolarTV`.`TABCONTRATOA` (`CPF` , `CDCONTR`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Tabela de assinantes\n';
```

Btw, this code was generated by mysql workbench

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30409/discussion-between-fabiotk-and-ypercube).

Answer (score 0):

150 means that the `FOREIGN KEYs` are being established in the wrong order.

Plan A:  Do the `CREATE TABLEs` in an order that does not violate FK issues.

Plan B:  Don't start with FKs; add them later.  (There may still be an ordering issue.)